# What are the meaning of some of the "deeper" insights metrics? Why is my Daily Organic Reach less than my Daily Reach of Page Posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I use FB Insights data everyday when running analysis for my company.  However, I have had some inconsistencies in the data and don't know if it is caused by a misunderstanding of the meaning of the "deeper" metrics.  I have searched everywhere and am hoping that someone can help me.

1. Key Metrics tab:

   1. Why is my Daily Organic Reach less than my Daily Reach of Page Posts?  What is the count delta from?  What is not included in Daily Organic Reach this included in Daily Reach of Page Posts?
   2. Can you reach the same person Organically and Virally?  Why does Organic Reach + Viral Reach equal to more than Total Reach (and Paid Reach is 0)?
2. ‘Daily Likes Sources’ tab:

   1. What are the full definitions of each of the sources: profile_connect, mobile, api, recommended_pages, page_suggestions, timeline, external_connect, page_profile, hovercard, search, ticker, like_story
   2. Are mobile likes independent of the others?
   3. Why would the Daily New Likes column in the Key Metrics tab not equal the summation all the columns for the same day in the Daily Likes Sources tab?
3. ‘Daily Viral Reach by Story Type’ tab:

   1. What are the full definitions of each of the story types: fan, page post, user post, mention?
   2. If we normally get 1-5 viral uniques from user post, and then one day get 1.5k, what is the likely source of this?
4. ‘Daily Page Consumers by Consumption Type’ tab:

   1. What are the full definitions of the consumption types: other click, link click
   2. Are photo views and video views included in other clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have only recently started using facebook insights and this is what I can share with you.

Q.  Why is my Daily Organic Reach less than my Daily Reach of Page Posts?

A.  As far as I understand these are two very different factors, Your organic reach is the number of people that find you through searches (Facebook, google, yahoo, bing ...) while Daily reach of page posts is the number of people visiting your page due to internal efforts, such as posting status updates.

Q. Can you reach the same person Organically and Virally?

A. Organic was explained previously while Viral is an effect of other people sharing your posts, be it images, statuses or videos. In general if you have interesting updates your viral reach will be higher than your organic reach. So basically yes, this just means that you are reaching a target audience using two different methods of marketing (If you are achieving in this, then keep it up, the more platforms people see you on, the comfortable they become with your brand)

The rest of your paragraph is very difficult for me to follow, please could you re-write in an easier point per question format.

Answer (score 0):

1.1  I have explained why the organic reach is less, if you want to increase your organic reach you need to do some SEO (Search Engine Optimization) I really hope you know what it means.
Im not quite sure what count delta is, but I am assuming that if it refers to organic vs posts then it would be the difference between them. I am not 100% sure of what factors are included in each type of reach (Sorry, but I suggest you do some more research on that)

1.2 To re-iterate, these are two different forms of online marketing so simply yes, you can reach the same person by doing both forms of marketing. Paid reach is affected by many things, first it depends on whether you are doing ppc (pay per click) or cpm (pay per impression). Here you will need to run multiple campaigns and set your ctr targets, then compare the results and choose which is better. You need keep repeating this to continuously optimize your spending per person entering your page.

2.1 profile_connect - A like through a friend
    mobile - A like from the mobile site (m.facebook.com)
    api - This would be if you have the api on an external website of yours
    recommended_pages - Liked by someone cause a friend posted it to them either in chat or in a PM
    page_suggestions - I think this is if another page has liked you and refers people to you, but not 100% sure
    timeline - No clue, this is new to FB and I havent had a chance to look at it yet ;)
    external_connect - This would be from an external website, similar to the api, but rather just a url link as opposed to the api (can be found on forums...)
    page_profile - ??
    hovercard - ??
    search - Facebook search
    ticker - ??
    like_story - Some one that came to your page because they saw a post of yours (true Viral)
2.2 I highly doubt that mobile like are independant of others, I just dont think that f-book has setup proper tracking for their mobile site

2.3 I think that people removing their likes may cause this, but I have asked myself this question a number of times :/
3.1 ok well you need to understand that viral reach is when a friend of a fan sees the post.
    fan - A friend of a fan acted on a post that they saw (eg: John likes top-racers fan page)
    page post - you share your page and it lands up on a fans wall and one of their friends act on it
    user post - you post to your page ...
    mention - A fan mentions you in one of their posts (the strongest viral)
3.2 Well this is a tough one because I don't know what you did, but I would suggest you list everything you do and when this happens have a look to see what you did different (sometimes viral really is viral)
4. I have never looked into these, sorry.

I hope this information helps you, but I really would suggest that you try and do some more research on the topic. Remember that Google tactics aren't necessarily going to work in Facebook, especially with paid advertising.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Very useful information.  I appreciate you taking the time to look into my questions.  The only one I am still a bit hazy on is 1.2.  I understand differences between organic, viral, and paid, I just wasnt sure as to why my Organic+Viral+Paid did not equal Total Reach.  Everything else was fantastic.

Comment: I haven't checked this, but I would assume that the total reach would be the unique number of entries, where as Organic would be the unique number of organic, same for Viral and for Paid. So if one person comes in under Viral and paid, you would be counting him twice, where as the total reach would only count him once.